# How to calculate memory usage of an object?

Tags: java, caching, memory-management

I'm implementing a caching system for android app, I need to add a parameter that specify the maximun amount of memory permited for caching, but I don't know how to calculate the memory used for an object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [In Java, what is the best way to determine the size of an object?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object)

Answer (score 1):

Apparently 1.5 added an instrumentation interface. Check out this article

http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=83

you can use a getObjectSize() method. Its implementation specific and an approximation but better than nothing

Comment: It is a good option but not for android :'( 

"The java.lang.instrument package was removed from dalvik core library, 
because this package makes a fundamental assumption that the execution 
format being used by the VM is a .class file. .class files do not appear on 
Android at all. "  http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/311e16daba10dd7c

Comment: check this post out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52353/in-java-what-is-the-best-way-to-determine-the-size-of-an-object One of the guys says there may be a C-like sizeOf() implementation floating around

Comment: sizeOf uses Internally   java.lang.instrument  http://www.google.com/codesearch/p?hl=en#JJilFFvKD1Y/trunk/Java/%E4%BE%8B%E5%AD%90/SizeOf/src/net/sourceforge/sizeof/SizeOf.java&q=net.sourceforge.sizeof.SizeOf&d=8

Comment: http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/javatips/jw-javatip130.html - This is what I was referring to. Its old as dirt and probably not particularly useful because it relies are triggering garbage collection which is unreliable at best and comparing heap sizes. I'm not sure there is a good way to do this if you can't use the Intstrumentation stuff

Answer (score 0):

You can consider getting a heap dump of the application and observing its Retained Heap

Comment: To produce a heap dump use heapViewer (since JDK5.0). It is located in %JDK_HOME%\demo\jvmti\heapViewer You can start the feature from the command line with th -agentlib option. You can trigger the dump with a Ctrl-C or Ctrl-\ (SIGQUIT).

Answer (score -1):

It depends on the object. Calculate how much memory each part of the object takes when allocated to get a baseline for the max size the object can be.

Comment: Consider providing an example of how to do this.